# Will an exception in an async plugin stop a creation of an instance?

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm talking to a customer who has re-registered one of their plugin to asynchronous position and they claim that their experience "weird behavior". According to the description, it seems that when an exception is thrown in the async plugin (message create), the process is not rolled back. The instance is created.

Is that an intended behavior? And if so, what can be done to stop it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asynchronous plugins are not executed inside the main operation transaction, this means that when an exception is thrown the main operation is not rolled back.

The common example is the creation of a task inside a plugin when a new account is created:

If the plugin is synchronous and an `InvalidPluginExecutionException` is thrown in your plugin, both account and task will not be created and the error is prompted to the user.

If the plugin is asynchronous and an `InvalidPluginExecutionException` is thrown in your plugin, the account will be created, the task will not be created and no error is prompted to the user.

[MSDN - Event Execution Pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941.aspx)

Comment: Great answer to part one, Guido. Now the other part - how to stop it? The customer wants the plugin to be async due to some unclear performance consideration.

Comment: If the requirement is to roll back the creation of the record, the plugin musts be registered as synchronous. An alternative is to catch the exception inside the plugin and manually delete the record (but in this way you have no power if other processes will start after the creation of the record). About performance issues, I don't know the business logic inside the plugin but normally a synchronous plugin just hangs for few seconds the form before it's saved, isn't a big deal in most of the cases.

Comment: @GuidoPreite I get the async plugin is not part of the create account message pipeline. My question is does the async plugin itself have a message processing pipeline itself? e.g. in the example above, if the async plugin creates 2 tasks and is registered pre-operation, task 1 succeeds but task 2 fails, will task 1 create be rolled back?